# Example of a non abelian group that is generated by subgroups that centralize each other

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find an example of a non-abelian group $G$ such that $G=\langle \bigcup G_i  \rangle$ where each $G_i$ is simple subgroup of $G$ and for all $i,j$ we have $x\in G_i, y\in G_j\implies xy=yx $. I know that the direct sum of simple groups would work, but I am trying to find something that is not described on a product of sets (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: The $G_i$ are all normal subgroups of $G$, so $G$ must be a direct product of the nonabelian $G_i$ and some subset of the abelian $G_i$.